# Extracting InputStream from ServerRequest

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have been wanting to extract an inputStream from a `reactive.function.server.ServerRequest` body but to no avail. I have so far tried out some of the ways I found here and elsewhere and ended up with the same issue all over again which is that ->

Given this excerpt:

[image]

I get this inputStream upon inspection, which is clearly not right:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas if it is actually possible to achieve such a conversion in my case using `PipedInputStream` or indeed any other object?

Answer (score 2):

a `DataBuffer` can itself do the job. It has an `asInputStream` method.

However, you may be asking the wrong question:

Almost all InputStreams, and certainly the inputstream from a network connection, **fundamentally is a blocking concept**, and you're using reactive, which means **your code is fundamentally broken if you block**.

In other words, as a general rule of thumb, 'I use reactive!' and 'I want an inputstream!' are mutually exclusive. You.. don't want an inputstream.

If you must, you want a bit of an exotic unicorn: An InputStream that guarantees that it doesn't block. There's really only one such way to create such a beast, which is to pump ALLLLL the data into memory (let's hope it's not a particularly large amount of data!) and then make an inputstream that just provides the bytes already loaded in memory: Such a stream does not block. `ByteArrayInputStream` is one example of such a stream. Presumably the `asInputStream` method of DataBuffer is another.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any source online that demonstrates your idea in practice? Would much appreciate it!